# Add multiple environment variables from docker to kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, cloud

I'm a newbie regarding kubernetes. I need to 'convert' these docker commands to kubernetes so I can deploy runtime from Kubernetes to cloud.

```
`docker run -d -e AP_USERNAME=test1 -e AP_PASSWORD=test2 -e AP_ENVIRONMENT=test3 -e AP_ORGANIZATION="test4" -e AP_ARM_SERVER_NAME="test5" test/docker-mule:0.1`
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a pod definition file / manifest with Environment variables in it as below and create it in k8s cluster as `kubectl create -f <pod-definition-file.yaml>`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: docker-mule-pod
  labels:
    name: docker-mule-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: docker-mule-pod
    image: test/docker-mule:0.1
    env:
    - name: AP_USERNAME
      value: "test1"
    - name: AP_PASSWORD
      value: "test2"
    - name: AP_ENVIRONMENT
      value: "test3"
    - name: AP_ORGANIZATION
      value: "test4"
    - name: AP_ARM_SERVER_NAME
      value: "test5"
```

You can also create [ConfigMaps](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/) and/or [Secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) which you can refer to in pod definition file.

Comment: Hello Sandeep! Thank you for your suggestion. Is there a way that we can input environment variables using cli only? Like a docker run, and not create a yaml file

Comment: @Austine, you work with pod in k8s, not a container as in docker tool. If you need a cli version, you could do something like  `kubectl run pod-name --image=<dockerImage> --env="DNS_DOMAIN=cluster" --env="POD_NAME=pod-name"`